# The way to store external session to cookies after authentication with next-auth

Tags: express, next.js, session-cookies, next-auth

I am using the Google authentication feature in next-auth and would like to manage the session on an external server. Therefore, I tried calling the session using next-auth's callbacks after successful authentication, but the session information retrieved from the external server is not being stored.

front host: localhost:3000 (nextjs)
back  host: localhost:10613(nodejs express)

external server session setting :

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(
  session({
    name: "session ID",
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new FileStore(),
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      httpOnly: false,
      secure: false,
    },
  })
);
```

next-auth callbacks:

```
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ account, profile }) {

        const fetchUserInfo = async () => {
          try {
            const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:10613/sessionchk", {
              withCredentials: true,
            });
            return response.data;
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return null;
          }
        };
        const data = await fetchUserInfo();
      return true; 
    },
  },
```

front cookies info:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPEfT.png)